# Passing extra parameter into plot method makes sympy fail?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.stats import Normal, cdf
from sympy import init_printing

def euro_vanilla_call_sym(S, X, T, r, sigma):
    N = Normal('x',0,1) # define random variable

    d1 = sy.ln(S/X) + ((r+0.5*sigma**2)*T)/(sigma*sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sigma*sy.sqrt(T)

    call = S*cdf(N)(d1) - X*sy.exp(-r*T) * cdf(N)(d2)

    return call
```

^^^ code for replication.

```
x = Symbol("x")
euro_price_var = euro_vanilla_call_sym(10,15,10,.02,x)
p = plot(euro_price_var, (x,0,2.1), xlabel="Stock_Price", ylabel="Option_Value")
fig = p._backend.fig
ax = p._backend.ax
ax[0].xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,0)
ax[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-.1,.5)

fig
```

Works but prints the plot twice which I don't want. So I thought this would fix it.

```
x = Symbol("x")
euro_price_var = euro_vanilla_call_sym(10,15,10,.02,x)
p = plot(euro_price_var, (x,0,2.1), xlabel="Stock_Price", ylabel="Option_Value", show=False)
fig = p._backend.fig
ax = p._backend.ax
ax[0].xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,0)
ax[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-.1,.5)

fig
```

Which then fails but the only thing that changed is I passed in `show=False`

---

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it "prints the plot twice". It seems to work fine in isympy.

Comment: Added an image!

Comment: What enironment are you working in? Is that Jupyter? QtConsole?

Comment: jupyter notebook!

Comment: I think this might be a bug in sympy or jupyter. Can you open an issue on github for sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues